# Proof checking $\liminf cx_n = c \limsup x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I just started to work with $\limsup$'s and $\liminf$'s and I would like to know if my proof of the identity

\begin{equation}
\liminf cx_n = c \limsup x_n
\end{equation}

with $x_n$ a bounded sequence and $c\leq0$ is correct.

Let $a = \limsup x_n$ and $\epsilon>0$. Then

\begin{equation}
x_n < a+\epsilon
\end{equation}

for $n$ sufficiently large. Multiplying by $c$ we get the inequeality

\begin{equation}
c x_n >ca + c\epsilon
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
cx_n>ca-|c|\epsilon.
\end{equation}

That is $\liminf cx_n = ca$ which implies  $\liminf cx_n = c\limsup x_n$.

Comment: An easier way: $\liminf x_n = - \limsup (-x_n)$, and constant multiplication is clear.

Comment: I know, but if $c=-1$, is my proof correct?

Comment: Last inequality doesn't show exactly that $\lim inf cx_n = ca$. You need to prove that $ca$ is a limiting point

Comment: You can prove this with k being a nonempty up-bounded set sup(-k) =-inf(k)

Answer (score 1):

What you did only proves that $ca\leqslant\liminf_ncx_n$. You can prove that you actually have an equality by proving that some subsequence of the sequence $(cx_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $ca$ But that is easy. Take a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ whose limit is $a$ and then $\lim_kcx_{n_k}=ca$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, for $\liminf x_n$ to exist, it is enough to prove that for sufficiently large $n$, $\liminf x_n - \epsilon\leq x_n$. That's why I didn't have to consider the inequality $\liminf cx_n \leq ca$.

Comment: So for reference, the full theorem is here: $a=\liminf x_n$ if and only if whenever $\alpha < a$, $\lbrace n\in\mathbb{N}: x_n < \alpha\rbrace$ is finite and whenever $a<\beta$ we have $\lbrace   n\in\mathbb{N} : x_n < \beta\rbrace$ is infinite.

Comment: The statement from your first comment makes no sense, since it is circular. On the other hand, the “full theorem” of your second comment it correct indeed.

Comment: I can't see how is circular. First I proved that for $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $n$, $x_n < \limsup x_n + \epsilon$ (this the alternative characterisation of $\limsup$). Then I can multiply by $c \leq 0$ to get $cx_n > c\limsup x_n - |c| \epsilon$. This is the "$\alpha$-statement" in my theorem, so I can conclude $\liminf cx_n = c\limsup x_n$.

Comment: Indeed, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there are only finitely many $n$'s such that $\liminf_nx_n-\varepsilon\leqslant x_n$. But it is not true that $\liminf_nx_n$ is the only number with that property. Actually, every number smaller than $\liminf_nx_n$ has that property too.